# In bashrc, tell bash to always call the same command

Tags: bash

When logging to a shell, I want that all command executed in the current .bashrc profile to be "redirected" to the same command.

Example:

```
ls /home/bin/
foo

home$ foo
# will call /home/bin/foo given the right $PATH

home$ bar
# will give "command not found" how can i make it so it call foo?
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, so you are asking even if you try to execute `bar`, it should execute `foo`? and same for every  command?? you type `ls` and press enter, it should execute `foo`????

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. And ideally foo would be called like this: `foo bar`

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want that behavior for? Maybe there're other ways of achieving it.

Comment: At work, we already have a system where we add or own command. Right now, when we want to create a new command, we must do something lke this ln -s /home/bin/bar /home/bin/foo. We have to rewrite our system, but for now I was looking into a simpler short time solution that doesn't add or remove files when a command is added or removed dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` version 4 and greater, if you define a function called `command_not_found_handle`, `bash` will call that whenever it fails to find a command. You can use that to run an alternate command.

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    missing_command=$1
    shift
    arguments=$@
    echo "$missing_command not found, running 'foo' instead"
    foo
}
```

Put that in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to implement this is to create wrapper shell prompt, i.e. a shell script which is interactive

```
MY_PROMPT='$ '
while :
do
  echo -n "$MY_PROMPT"
  read line
  foo "$line"
  done

exit 0
```

This will take user input and pass it to foo. But still i'm wondering for what you need this? I'm not aware of any bash option